# Paypal Integration with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal payment gateway with codeigniter. i have written the form along all the details but when i submit the form Paypal says

> There's a problem with the merchant's PayPal account. Please try again later.

[image]

**Here is my Form which i am submitting.**

```
 <?php 


  echo form_open('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
  echo form_hidden('upload', 1 );
  echo form_hidden('cmd', '_cart' );
  echo form_hidden('bussiness', 'my email goes here' );
  echo form_hidden('curruncy_code', 'GBP' ); 
   echo form_hidden('custom', '3652652' );


  $count =  0 ;
  foreach ($cart_data as $item)
  {
    $count++;
    $item_name = $item['name'];
    $item_price = $item['price'];
    $item_qty = $item['qty'];

    echo form_hidden('item_name_'.$count, $item_name );
    echo form_hidden('amount_'.$count, $item_price );
    echo form_hidden('item_qty_'.$count, $item_qty );

  }

  echo form_submit('submit','Submit');
  echo form_close();


  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i was misspelling 'business' .
When i corrected my mistake i began to work normally.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to pass business email in form

```
echo form_hidden('business', 'my email goes here' );
```

Change to

```
echo form_hidden('business', 'yourbusiness@email.com' ); // Enter Proper email address here
```